# Specific revision of VCS root for checkout in teamcity

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have the checkout rules applied in my TeamCity(v8.0.6) step to grab some files from the repository.

There is a VCS root configured for the SVN repository. I would like to checkout files from the specific svn revision. Is it possible? Now it is only using the latest revision.

Regards,
jbk

Answer (score 2):

You can [run a custom build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Triggering+a+Custom+Build#TriggeringaCustomBuild-Changes) on specific revision. However TeamCity displays only the changes detected earlier for the current build configuration VCS roots.
At the moment it's only possible to specify any revision for Perforce. Here is the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-11400) you can vote for.